# Angular - Should HttpClientModule be in the Exports array in the CoreModule?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-modules

Well, I'm structuring my project following the infrastructure of:

- Feature module.
- Core module.
- Shared module.

But there's something that I still don't have clear enough.

As far as I know, the `HttpClientModule` should be in the `CoreModule` because well,... it provides the `HttpClient` service to make HTTP requests to a server.

Now, the `imports` array allows an Angular module to use functionalities provided in other modules, and the `exports` array allows an Angular module to expose some of its functionalities.

I have this in my `CoreModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            enableTracing: true
        })
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class CoreModule {
}
```

Now, since my `CoreModule` is imported in my `AppModule`, shouldn't the `HttpClientModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` be exported as well? Just as the `RouterModule`.

I'm seeing the `CoreModule` and `SharedModule` like some sort of bridge.

The `SharedModule` makes more sense to me:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatButtonModule
    ],
    exports: [
        MatButtonModule
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

The `SharedModule` imports the `MatButtonModule` and then export it so that other modules can make use of it.

Shouldn't the `CoreModule` be the same way? Because the App runs fine; however, I'm in dev-mode.

Hope I was clear enough and someone can help me to brush out this doubt.

Answer (score 6):

**No, the `exports` array of an NgModule shouldn't include modules without components, directives, or pipes (like `HttpClientModule`).**

The purpose of exporting something from an NgModule is to give other modules (or things within those other modules) access to **this module's components, directives, and pipes**—and also sometimes to give those other modules access to (i.e. re-export) components, directives, and pipes from some other module as a convenience.

Your `CoreModule` lists `RouterModule` as an export so that anything importing your `CoreModule` can use the `routerLink` attribute directive (among other things).  That is, `RouterModule` exports components, directives, and/or pipes.

As the `HttpClientModule` doesn't declare any **components, directives, or pipes**, there is no value in listing it as an NgModule export.

These [Angular guide](https://angular.io/docs) [NgModule FAQs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq) may also be useful:

- [What should I export?](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-should-i-export)
- [What should I *not* export?](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-should-i-not-export)

Comment: Thanks for the links

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that BrowserAnimationsModule could and should be imported in the AppModule itself.

You do not need to export HttpClientModule if all your services that uses HttpClient is in CoreModule itself.

Even if you do use HttpClient in other modules, you could just import HttpClientModule in that particular module, or do it in AppModule (except for lazy loaded modules).

Comment: Possibly someone took umbrage with your second paragraph, which suggests that there might be some other case where exporting a provider-only NgModule is acceptable (there is none).

Comment: "The CoreModule could also be used to export any third party module that is required in the AppModule. The idea is to keep AppModule as lean as possible"

https://blog.chai-jay.com/angular-core-vs-shared-modules/